# Using the result from part of a python function and store in variable outside function

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program I am calling a function that imports .csv data into a `treeview` using `tkinter` and `csv` module. The Function is only called when the `Import` button is used. The `import` button is linked to function `select_input_file`. The function works as expected and the csv data is imported into my `treeview` without any issues. From here I would like to store some of the function results into `variables` outside the function. For instance the `input_file_path` which will only contain a value once the function is called and a file is imported. Also data imported into `Ro Number, Rego Number` columns. I have attempted to use `return()` but it stops the function from running any further. I have also read up on `yield` but through documentation im not sure if this is my best option. I thought a solution could be to use `return()` and then `for in rdr:`after each return so the `select_input_file` function continued but Im sure theres a better way?? Ive cut the code down to what I thought was necessary.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
import csv


root = tk.Tk()

treetime = tkrttk.Treeview(root)
treetime['columns'] = ("Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5",
                       "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11")

def select_input_file():
            input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
            with open(input_file_path) as csv_file:
              rdr = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
              for row in rdr:
                 RoNumber = row['Ro Number']
                 DateIn = row['Date In']
                 TimeIn = row['Time In']
                 TimeOut = row['Time Out']
                 RegoNumber = row['Rego Number']
                 CustomerName = row['Customer Name']
                 VehicleMake = row['Vehicle Make']
                 VehicleModel = row['Vehicle Model']
                 JobDescription = row['Job Description']
                 CurrentStatus = row['Current Status']

                 treetime.insert("", 0, values=(RoNumber, DateIn, TimeIn, TimeOut, RegoNumber,
                                           CustomerName, VehicleMake, VehicleModel, JobDescription, CurrentStatus))

menubar=Menu(root)
filemenu=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Import", command=select_input_file)
               
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can make `input_file_path` a global variable and create a list (also in global scope) to hold the returned records.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question: you can't `return` and continue executing within a function.  You could get that effect with `yield`, but I think it would be abusing the semantics and could just give you future headaches.
You *can* `return` more than one thing:

```
def foo():
    return "Spam", 42

def bar():
    name, answer = foo()
```

This would let you return (e.g.) the selected filename and data from the file to the calling function.

A more general comment: functions should generally do one thing.  This makes them easier to test (the purpose is clear) and easier to modify (fewer if any side effects).  Right now your function is getting user input (filename), loading and parsing the file contents, and updating the control.  You may want to have separate functions that do these different things, and are just brought together by a short function that is invoked when 'Import' is clicked.  Your original question might be easier to address this way, too.

Comment: Is the issue here that when we use `name, answer = foo()` it will call the function when the program is started?

Comment: Yes, you're right - if that assignment is left as a bare line outside a function definition.  I've updated my answer to show that assignment happening inside another function that calls foo().

Comment: thanks for the reply, yep as you said I think I need to split that function up. So using your answer in my code 
`return input_file_path` `def(get_filename): filename=input_file_path()`
How will I get the return of `filename` if its stored with another function `get_filename` or have I totally misunderstood?